# Use Windows Store controls in a Windows 8 desktop app?

Tags: windows-8, metro

Is it possible to use the Windows 8 Store controls in a Windows 8 desktop app? Controls like the FlipView and SemanticZoom would be useful.

I haven't found any information about this and would presume the answer is no, but thought someone would have a more definitive answer.

Comment: XAML or HTML? Please. Learn something about platform you are developing for before asking.

Comment: XAML. It seems pretty clear the HTML is only for store apps. I guess I'm asking more if Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls is available in desktop apps.

Answer (score 3):

Well if my reading comprehension was better, I'd have seen the answer was right on the MSDN page. It's no. :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx